# Stable sorting a vector using std::sort

Tags: c++

So I have some code like this, I want to sort the vector based on `id` and put the last overridden element first:

```
struct Data {
  int64_t id;
  double value;
};
std::vector<Data> v;

// add some Datas to v
// add some 'override' Datas with duplicated `id`s

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(),
  [](const Data& a, const Data& b) {
    if (a.id < b.id) {
      return true;
    } else if (b.id < a.id) {
      return false;
    }
    return &a > &b;
});
```

Since vectors are contiguous, `&a > &b` should work to put the appended overrides first in the sorted vector, which should be equivalent to using `std::stable_sort`, but I am not sure if there is a state in the `std::sort` implementation where the equal values would be swapped such that the address of an element that appeared later in the original vector is earlier now. I don't want to use `stable_sort` because it is significantly slower for my use case. I have also considered adding a field to the struct that keeps track of the original index, but I will need to copy the vector for that.

It seems to work here: https://onlinegdb.com/Hk8z1giqX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::sort` gives no guarantees whatsoever on when elements are compared, and in practice, I strongly suspect most implementations will misbehave for your comparator.

The common `std::sort` implementation is either plain quicksort or a hybrid sort (quicksort  switching to a different sort for small ranges), implemented in-place to avoid using extra memory. As such, the comparator will be invoked with the same element at different memory addresses as the sort progresses; you can't use memory addresses to implement a stable sort.

Either add the necessary info to make the sort innately stable (e.g. the suggested initial index value) or use `std::stable_sort`. Using memory addresses to stabilize the sort won't work.

For the record, having experimented a bit, I suspect your test case is too small to trigger the issue. At a guess, the hybrid sorting strategy works coincidentally for smallish `vector`s, but breaks down when the `vector` gets large enough for an actual quicksort to occur. Once I increase your `vector` size with some more filler, the stability disappears, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZRNi9swEIbv@hVDCsbZdb1xEnZpYnxJ74VeeihLkOWJI9aWjD5ClyW/PVXkdZsu21iHlS5i5nlnhhcxrOs@s4aK@nS6u/nQQwhcPd9EwwXC5vYWNrLteIMqfSvZyAqTIZ3AdyuAigq@Ymlrr@yUrBVtQfpiKfmhuEF4llYBc1rgAsyea8CKG6m8uFOoNUxcrQmU1hjpEOlo38MT@AuZdWW4SQn5WFNu7sgnLlhj3Ww5bWrp5t23xUWQS20U0n9iB2Ru@suINbzh5rkgVnNRg6At6o4yBG2qNSFcGGgpF/GUvHhP@wp5R7nKXfJ@uTUJVNKWDRYFHNY9lHZW77clZU9xS59we8bjLIEv6SKbTkegWTobgeYeml@HFiGVemgx2m6RZsvRwYOgebrMQqCHUehh1MxQn7IQn7IQn@ZhFgRAWYhPWYhP968@ecp969VKS2XiQ1piff7ZiZOiqNzDEz8f43d/dwQ0GdbKf4ByCi8DwncQ03THlTaQQ9m/LvLno9BY5baGsrge4kfARqOXl3/k9Jp8R53grf49MKJQQFT@Rf3jOFizc3stptbIKAKEFRwu2zFp3SA54DBTDhN3fUQjk27b9aG@@rEv@dp4tiYuQE6n3w)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to use `stable_sort` such that the relative ordering of equal elements is reversed?

Comment: @17andLearning: you can do a second pass to reverse equivaelent element

Comment: @Jarod42: Or to avoid caring about equivalent elements in a post-sort pass, just unconditionally reverse the contents of the whole sequence up front. A pre-sort pass with `std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());` will naturally make `stable_sort` preserve stability in reverse.